# Does IoTHub delay messages by a batching interval in a custom endpoint to Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am sending some messages in a pipeline using Azure IoT Edge. There is a custom endpoint (say, *GenericEndpoint*) that I have set up, which will send/put the messages to Azure Blob storage. I am using a route to push the device messages to the specific endpoint *GenericEndpoint*.

The batch frequency of *GenericEndpoint* is set at 60 seconds. So 1 batch creates 1 single file with some messages, in the container specified.

Lets say, there are *N* messages in a single blob batch file (say, *blobX*) in the specific container. If I take the average of the difference between the *IoTHub.EnqueuedTime*(i) of each message i, in *blobX* and the 'Creation Time' of *blobX*, and call it *AVG*, I get:

[image: average]

I think, this essentially gives me the average time that those *N* messages spent in iothub before being written in the blob storage. Now what I observe here is that, if *p* and *q* are respectively the first and last message written in *blobX*, then

[image: ss] 
[image: ss]

But since the batching interval was set to 60 seconds, I would expect this average or *AVG* to be approximately near 30 seconds. Because, if the messages are written as soon as they arrive, then the average for each batch file would be near 30 seconds.

But in my case, *AVG* ≈ 90 seconds, which suggests the messages wait for atleast approximately one batching interval (60 seconds in this case) before being considered for a particular batch.

**Assumption:** When a batch of messages are written in a blob file, they are written all at once.

**My question**:

Is this delay of one batch interval or 60 seconds intentional? If yes, then I assume it will change on changing the batching interval to say 100 seconds.

If, no, then, does it usually take 60 seconds to process a message in iothub and then send it through a route to a custom endpoint? Or am I looking at this from a completely wrong angle?

I apologize beforehand if my question seems confusing.

Comment: Yes, I also found the difference between the IoTHub.EnqueuedTime of the first and last message of the blob sometimes more than the Batch frequency I set. I am confirming this issue with the related engineer and I need your help. Can you show your test result including Batch frequency value and blob created frequency? It is better if you can show some snapshots. Thanks.

Comment: The following is 60s [batching frequency] (https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HzCmUDr.png) and the [resultant blob files](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HzCmBFB.png) in the snapshot. Also tried for [120s batching freq](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HzClle3.png) and [resulting blobs](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HzCm5jJ.png) delay of **first**and **last** msg and blob creation time is about 160s and 60s. Not sure if this helps. We can take this offline as well. Is it possible to try with different batching intervals and see whether the delay is exactly 1 batching interval or not? Let me know if I can help more.

Comment: Hi Anirban, I didn't see 160s interval, can you point me out? It seems the results are 60s for batching frequency set to 60s and 120s for batching frequency set to 120s, right?

Comment: Hi, please look into the [attached pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1600r32PMudvwe9O8LPm6b8svgPk1JMzW) for more details. I attached screenshots for easy reference. The example run is for 120 seconds batching. Once again, to reiterate, I am interested in how much time on average a message spends in the hub before being written to a blob file.

Comment: Hi Anirban, thanks for pdf result, it is very clear. I'll send your result to related engineer to help your issue.

Comment: @AnirbanDas This latency could be attributed to IoT Hub routing processed message internally to event hub which in turn then sends the D2C message to Azure Storage. This additional processing time is expected behavior when routing messages from IoT Hub to Azure storage. However there is no official document describe it. The best way to know about it is test the time by setting different batch interval.

Comment: And if you have good ideas or feedback about Azure IoT Hub, you can try submit from [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot)